# When to repeat antiphons during the Liturgy of the Hours?

Tags: prayer, liturgy-of-the-hours

I've been praying the Morning and Evening prayers in the Liturgy of the Hours pretty consistently for the past few weeks. I've got the four volume set. I'd been praying the Invitatory for Morning Prayer off the card they included, for a while, but I misplaced it so I went to find it in the book and lo and behold it says to repeat the antiphon in between verses.

So, what I was wondering is, for private recitation, is repeating the antiphon between verses appropriate and if so, are you supposed to repeat the antiphons for the psalms and canticle as well and the book just doesn't say this because that would be way too much to print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is up to you. In general, you do repeat it when you are praying together with other people, but if you are on your own, you can choose whether you want repeat the antiphon after each strophe of the invitatory.

The antiphon at the beginning of the psalms or canticles should always be recited or sung, but you can choose whether to repeat it at the end of psalm. Only in the invitatory is customary to repeat the antiphon after each strophe. You can read that in the [General Instruction on the Liturgy of Hours](https://www.liturgyoffice.org.uk/Resources/Rites/GILH.pdf). Read especially the numbers 34-36 and 110-120. I use also the 4-volume set where this is explained in the Ordinary and also the iBreviary app either on my mobile phone or in my browser. The fact that you can omit the antiphon repetition in the invitatory is explained [here](http://www.ibreviary.com/m2/breviario.php?s=lodi).

Comment: But just the invitatory, not the rest of the psalms?  It's been a while since I've prayed the Liturgy of the Hours with anybody except my family so I can't remember some of the nuances.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that doubt.